# setTimeout() starts onload instead of onclick. How do I get it to start only after I click it?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have the setTimeout() function start only after I click a button as opposed to when the page loads.  Here is my code:

```
function convert() {
'use strict';
var utcDate = new Date();
var message;
var output = document.getElementById('output2');
message = 'today is ' + utcDate.toUTCString(); 
if (output.textContent !== undefined) {
    output.textContent = message;
} else {
    output.innerText = message;
}
document.getElementById('output2').value = message;
}
button.onclick = setTimeout(convert, 5000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to start on click of the button. Than you this should be the way:

```
button.onclick = function() { setTimeout(convert, 5000); }
```

Answer (score 3):

change

```
button.onclick = setTimeout(convert, 5000);
```

to

```
button.onclick = function () { setTimeout(convert, 5000);}
```

or you could use jQuery if you are already loading the library for something else

```
$('#idOfButton').click(function () { setTimeout(convert, 5000);});  //more efficient than $.on()
```

or another way using jQuery

```
$('#idOfButton').on('click', function () { setTimeout(convert, 5000); });
```

As with many tasks in programming, there are many ways to accomplish your task

Answer (score 2):

```
button.onclick = function(){setTimeout(convert, 5000);}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the setTimeout part in a function. So that last line would look like

```
button.onclick = function(){setTimeout(convert,5000)}
```